# An error occurred while listing cloudwatch-logs relations: Rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

The following message is shown one in about 5 times when I was reloading in the AWS Lambda dashboard of a function.

```
An error occurred while listing cloudwatch-logs relations: Rate exceeded (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ThrottlingException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null)
```

I don't understand what `Rate exceeded` means.
Please someone teach me how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: You can only make so many api calls (and refreshing/reloading the page or data is an api call) per second. All it means is you're doing it too frequently. It's not a problem - just wait a second and try again.

Comment: I see. How can I see what is the action that caused its throttling?
@404